# Looking for computer resource monitoring/analysis software

Tags: monitoring, hardware, system-monitor

I'm looking for some software that can analyze/monitor the resource usage (e.g. CPU, RAM, I/O read/writes) of my computer over time (and hopefully be able to save it). Beyond that, I'm wondering if such software could watch certain programs for resource usage and possibly identify when it is limited by my current setup (e.g. if the program runs out RAM, it will note that). Part of what I'm trying to do is identify avenues for future upgrades.

I've been looking for software like this, but haven't been able to find anything.

I'd prefer that it be open source or at least free of charge, if at all possible. The target OS is Windows 7.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: System Chronicle is working on something similar at its early stage. Might worth checking it out at: http://www.syschr.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are looking for a task manager *alternative* with advanced features.

Here is a list of them:

- Process Explorer https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

It's from Microsoft and is a solid alternative to task manager and gives explanatory info about processes.

- System Explorer http://systemexplorer.net/

System Explorer is an advanced tool with much of the same raw power that can be found in both Process Explorer and Process Hacker. The basic interface is simple and straightforward, while the advanced features are hidden inside menus, resulting in an experience that’s welcoming to newbies, yet effective for power users.

I recommend System Explorer, as it is much more detailed and offers tab based browsing through processes.

If you ever need any others, see https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-powerful-alternatives-windows-task-manager/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python](http://python.org) + [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) to monitor and log a lot of system information.

- Free, Libre and FOSS
- Cross Platform
- Completely configurable

There are also some great packages built on psutil to give you a gui and more.

- https://github.com/nicolargo/glances
  [image: glances]
- https://github.com/google/grr - Combines results from multiple networked computers.
- https://github.com/Jahaja/psdash