# Monitor Hardware on Windows

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, hardware

Currently I am getting weird crashs on my machine. They behave like there is a power shortage or something similar. For this I want to monitor my Hardware and espacially write the data to a file since any visual representation is useless in my case.

GPU-Z lets me write out everything from my graphics card. Unfortunately I have not found a similar tool for CPU and RAM. I want to monitor CPU Load per core, CPU Temperature and allocated RAM. Is there a good tool, which can write these values in a file? I am using Windows 7

Comment: Related: [Looking for computer resource monitoring/analysis software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19181/185). Especially see [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/19186/185) which should fully match your needs ("monitor **and log** a lot of system information").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HWinfo can help you. It logs almost every sensor. Every voltage and frequency. Data is from cpu, gpu, motherboard, fans and disks.

You can start sensors and logging them to a csv file. Link: http://www.hwinfo.com/